# Как передать массив в миксин в pug?

Tags: pug

```
mixin dropdown(params)
  .iqdropdown.menu-open(id=`iqdropdown${params.idPostfix}`)
    p.iqdropdown-selection= params.selectionText
    
    .iqdropdown-menu

      each item in ['item1','item2','item3']
        .iqdropdown-menu-option(data-id='item1')
          p.iqdropdown-item= item
          .iqdropdown-item-controls
            button.button-decrement.empty
              i.icon-decrement
            span.counter 0
            button.button-increment
              i.icon-decrement.icon-increment


+dropdown({leftCaption:   'dropdown',
           selectionText: 'Сколько гостей',
           idPostfix:     '-2',
           items:         ['Взрослые','Дети','Младенцы'],
          })
```

нужно в each item in ['item1','item2','item3'] вместо ['item1','item2','item3'] передать params.items.

each item in params.items не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать параметры по умолчанию. В твоём случае, ты вероятно ещё добавил другие вызовы этого миксина, поэтому в одном вызове ты передаёшь все нужные параметры, а в другом какой-нибудь из них не указал. В итоге, webpack выдаёт ошибку при сборке, так как, например, не передав массив в другом вызове миксина, как раз и получается, что property length of undefined. Это говорит о том, что длина массива не указана, потому что ты его и не передавал в качестве аргумента в параметры миксина, для этого и нужны параметры по умолчанию во избежании ошибок сборки/компиляции.